# Jquery - what can I use instead of parent()

Tags: jquery

I have the following bit of code that tests for it's parent having a particular class:

```
 if ($(levelsdiv).parent().hasClass('aligntop')) {
```

and the html structure is:

```
 <div class="row col-md-12 aligntop">
   <div class="dropdown-submenu col-md-2 level-1">
      <ul>
         <li><a class="toggle" href="#">
```

My test works. However, I've been asked to change the test so that `parent()` isn't used. The argument being that if over time someone decided to change the page slightly the code will break. I have tried to use `find` and `closest` neither work.

> $(levelsdiv) = the div with the class level-1

so `$(levelsdiv').closest('div').hasClass('aligntop')` and
`$(levelsdiv').find('div').hasClass('aligntop')`

Comment: _"I have tried to use find and closest neither work."_ - You forgot to add those cases in your question.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52586400/edit) and add a [mcve] using the icon looking like `[<>]`  - your claim is not understandable. Unless you use an ID, you cannot rely on the DOM never being changed by a developer to break your selector

Comment: @mplungjan I have also been told Id's are a big no as earlier browsers don't always recognise them.  I've added my attempt to use `closest` and `find`. I don't see any other way around it other than using parent and for maintainability anyone changing the page should be looking at the code that goes with it and change where required to follow the new layout, but my boss wants a non-developer to be able to slot small pieces of html in such as advertisments without having to go into code.

Comment: IDs work in all normal browsers. Example of a no-no in my book:: Allowing a non-developer to add apostrophes and they choose a backtick or the quote used by the script that displays their string.

Comment: From the documentation on [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/): _"**Get the descendants** of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element."_); [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/): _"For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing **the element itself** and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree."_).

Comment: @bilpor - *"I have also been told Id's are a big no as earlier browsers don't always recognise them"* Whoever told you that is mistaken, `id`s work across all browsers and always have (in my experience, at least from 1997 onward). There are good reasons not to use `id`s, but them "not working" isn't one of them.

Comment: It took me 3 months to write a complex menu system using bootstrap with some heavy customisation, different layouts for pc, tablet and mobile. I used I'ds all over the place and parent() had to support all IE from 8 up, firefox, chrome, safari as a basic. All worked, but then asked to revisit it without using any id's, or thing such as the 'parent()' method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) does indeed work (`find` would not, it looks the wrong direction). You need to have a means of identifying the desired element. Looking at your HTML, one way to identify it is that it's a `row`, so:

```
if ($(levelsdiv).closest(".row").hasClass('aligntop')) {
```

...but that's just one way, and whether it's the way you and your team want to use is up to you. You may instead want to add a class specifically for this purpose:

```
<div class="row col-md-12 aligntop levels-container">
    <div class="dropdown-submenu col-md-2 level-1">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="toggle" href="#">
```

...and then:

```
if ($(levelsdiv).closest(".levels-container").hasClass('aligntop')) {
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't read the doc correctly on closest.....didn't realise you could do it on class.